# How to fill a grease pencil ring?

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

I have two nested circles which build a ring.

[image]

What I want to do is fill the ring and leave the inner circle transparent(I don't want to fill it with another color, I want background to become visible). But when I try to fill the ring, inner circle fills as well.

[image]

How can I make the inner circle transparent?

Comment: I don't really do grease pencil stuff but I'm guessing the outer and inner circle need to be in the same layer

Comment: Thanks @Motcho to reminding me but I tried it as well. I got same result when put them inside a layer.

Comment: Hi, Makan. I hope you don't mind my edit.

Comment: Your edit was really helpful @MartynasŽiemys Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE: As of version 2.91 we now have a **Holdout** option in the material settings which makes life much easier:

- Create a new material, check Fill and Holdout
- Use the paint bucket to fill in any area you want to be see-through, or just draw the inside of the ring using this material.

---

Old answer:

- Create a new layer and name it "hole"
- Draw a filled circle matching the ring's inner circle
- Turn down the opacity of the "hole" layer to `0.000`
- Switch to the fill layer (that filled the entire ring) and enable mask
- Add "hole" to the mask list and invert it by clicking on the square/circle icon

[image]

Comment: Thanks @wilks I added a new GP layer on top of other layers, then filled the inner circle with blue and finally set the blend mode of the new layer to Subtract at this time the inner circle became a shade of red.  Then I set the opacity of layer to 0 but again inner circle became red. I guess your answer should be correct and I might be do it in a wrong way. Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: sure, gimme a min to add some screenshots, should be clearer

Comment: dang, can't get substract to work anymore =( i must have changed some settings when i tried the first time. But i managed to make it happen with masks, updating my answer now

Comment: It works!!! @wilks you saved me! Thanks!!!

Comment: @Makan Great! you can accept the answer then